# mysql: how to limit to query?

Tags: mysql

I select records and group them by date and uid(which is not the primary key), and I need to page those records by date, how can I do it?
For example:

```
uid  date
1    2012-01-10
2    2012-01-10
3    2012-01-09
3    2012-01-09
3    2012-01-11
```

sql:

```
SELECT date, uid
FROM users
GROUP by date,`uid`
```

Results:

```
uid   date
1    2012-01-10
2    2012-01-10
3    2012-01-09
3    2012-01-11
```

Because I need to page those record by date, if I use sql like:

```
SELECT date, uid
FROM users
GROUP by date,`uid`
LIMIT 0,2
```

then I just get the records like this:

```
uid   date
1    2012-01-10
2    2012-01-10
```

. how can I page the record by date.
The results I want when page size is 2:

```
uid   date
1    2012-01-10
2    2012-01-10
3    2012-01-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date, uid
FROM users
WHERE date >= 'your date'
  AND date < 'your date' LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: but if I want to get of records of page 10, how can I know the beginning date and ending date?

Comment: Iam not exactly sure what you mean